# misbehaving bold text while using minipage

Tags: minipage

I am working on a report, and I have been making use of `minipage` to display tables side by side.

**Problem***

The tables are being displayed fine but it's the `textbf{`**some text**`}` that's giving me problems ,

The code is as follows

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{ Perforated Plate}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Point & Voltage (mv) \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{Without the perforated Plate}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Point & Voltage (mv) \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

**Note**

The perforated plate part has the 'perforated ' part over the first table and the Plate part makes it to the next side table ..

I was wondering if anyone could point out why it giving me trouble rather than an alternative.

Comment: With the code as is, the two minipages won't be next to each other, but rather one over the other.

Comment: @egreg over each other? but the tables were placed next to each other..

Comment: @nerorevenge perhaps in your actual document, but certainly not with the snippet you just provided (after suitable completion); the blank line between the tables will make them appear one below the other.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina actual document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are trying to achieve? Notice `\noindent` to suppress indentation and the `%` character after `\end{minipage}` to suppress a superfluous blank space. Also, if you want the `minipage`s to be side-by-side, don't leave blank lines between them; otherwise, each one will start a new paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\strut\textbf{Perforated Plate}\par
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Point & Voltage (mv) \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}% <--- important
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\strut\textbf{Without the perforated Plate}\par
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
Point & Voltage (mv) \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Heiko Oberdiek** suggested in a comment, adding `\strut` to both titles guarantees the same distance from the baseline of the titles to the tables top line.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted.But I don't understand why that one command in a situation like this makes all the difference

Comment: @nerorevenge without it, there's a spurious blank space. Also, in your code you had a blank line between the tables, so each table was starting a new paragraph.

Comment: `\vphantom{p}` can be added to the first "title" (or `\strut` in both titles) to get the same distance from the baseline of the title to the table top.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek nice suggestion. I incorporated it to my updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  each table starting a new paragraph would mean that the tables were not placed side-by-side right? but they were so!

Comment: @nerorevenge leaving a blank line between them won't place them side-by-side under normal conditions. Could you please provide a simple complete document (like the one in my answer), but leaving a blank line (as in the code in your question) and showing the tables side-by-side? You can upload this sample code elsewhere (pastebin, for example) and leave a link here.